# Bootstrap tables with child rows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to code a table with Bootstrap like this:

[image]

In each cell, I have to design something like:

[image]

I have no code yet, I have tried to develop the table but do not know how to make a cell in the Machine column has multiple cells associated with the other columns.

Can you help me? I'm going crazy haha.
Thanks!!

Comment: completeley unclear what you are asking bro - and please post your code here

Comment: I have no code yet, I have tried to develop the table but do not know how to make a cell in the Machine column has multiple cells associated with the other columns.  @messerbill

Comment: you do not need to post a working code version...just the stuff you tried and where you failed - so we can help you to fix your code

Comment: Why bootstrap? Use html table. There are `rowspan` and `colspan` properties that let you span a cell over several rows or columns. For data tables that's the way to go.

Comment: Totally agree. If you want to create a table, use a table. This is what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was trying to do

http://www.bootply.com/ge8BpQ0e3n

Thanks for the comments! And it's true, it's a html table and not a Bootstrap table.